# PHP Html in while loop

Tags: php, html, function

I have two html / css content. One of them floating left, the other one floating right.

I wanna pull data from my database, then putting them in a order. Left, right, left, right.

```
          $services = pullservices();
          while ($service = mysqli_fetch_object($services)){
                for ($i=1; $i<=mysqli_num_rows($services); $i++) {
                    if ($i % 2 == 0): ?>
                        Left HTML Content

                    <?php else: ?>
                       Right HTML Content

                    <?php
                        endif;
                      }
                    } 
                  ?>
```

I have 6 items on db. But that code keeps looping one data for 6 times and it doing that for all the data on db.

That is the pullservices function.

```
function pullservices()
{
    global $connect;
    $products_query_string = "SELECT 
     id,
     title_tr AS title,
     text_tr,
     short_text_tr,
     image,
     icon
     FROM services WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY ordering , title_tr";
    $products_query_run = mysqli_query($connect, $products_query_string);
    return $products_query_run;
```

Comment: Don't use the `for` inside the `while`. Don't use it at all.

Comment: There is more than one way of doing this. You can count `$i` yourself; You can negate a boolean variable every iteration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply by using a flag.
 (pseudo code):

```
$services = pullservices();
        $flag=0;
      while ($service = mysqli_fetch_object($services)){
                if ($flag==0): ?>

                    Left HTML Content
                    <?php $flag=1; ?>

                <?php else: ?>
                   Right HTML Content
                   <?php $flag=0; ?>
                <?php
                    endif;

                } 
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you might be able to do this would be to split the data from the recordset and call it later in the html like this

```
$services = pullservices();

$i=0;
$data=array(
    'left'  =>array(),
    'right' =>array()
);

while( $rs = mysqli_fetch_object( $services ) ){
    $key = $i % 2 == 0 ? 'right' : 'left';
    /* add the real data rather than placeholder data */
    $data[ $key ][]=sprintf('%s HTML Content %d', ucfirst( $key ), $i );
    $i++;
}




<div id='left'>
<?php
    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $data['left'] );
?>
</div>

<div id='right'>
<?php
    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $data['right'] );
?>
</div>
```

Comment: needs some sort of delimiter.. could be anything really - space, comma, linebreak etc